# open csv from different directory in python

Tags: python, csv, directory

Im trying to open a csv file as followed

My ipynb-file is in the following directory -> `/data/filename.ipynb`
where as my csv file is in the following directory -> `/data/preprocessed/processed_data.csv`

When i try to open the file with the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/preprocessed/processed_data.csv')
```

I get an exception that the file doesn't exist. Somehow I think I didn't quite understand how the directories work. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Remove the first `/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this-

```
df = pd.read_csv('preprocessed/processed_data.csv')
```

Comment: oh yeah i had one slash too much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `os` module with a relative path:

```
import os

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'path/to/file/processed_data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```